# CSS href vs inline stylesheet difference

Tags: html, css, href

I have a small CSS file with contents:

```
<style type="text/css">

li {
padding: 10px;
font-family:  Arial;
}

</style>
```

Supposed to leave some space between list elements and change the font.  Now, If I include this CSS file in the HTML like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/lists.css" type="text/css" />
```

it does not work :(.

However, if I include the actual CSS code inside the html "head" block, it works.

I really prefer sourcing CSS (so different files can share the code). Any idea whats wrong and how to fix?

regards,
JP

Comment: @JP19: You don't have to use spaces to break the tags. Use four spaces to indent each line of code. Or, highlight your code blocks and hit Ctrl+K and the editor will indent them for you automatically.

Comment: @Stefan, @JP19: I've rolled the edits back since I don't see anything changed in the question except the footnote. The formatting should be completely OK *and* syntax-highlighted properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to omit the

```
<style type="text/css">
```

and

```
</style>
```

tags from your `.css` files, as those are tags used only in HTML to denote CSS styles if you're including them in your page `<head>`. If you include them, the browser will attempt to treat them as CSS code, which it isn't, and that causes your stylesheet to not work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `script` tag in your css files. Just `li {..}` is enough.

Also, checking path (`./css/lists.css`) might help. If it has mistake, nothing will be included.

Comment: Path was correct (one nice way to check is view source in browser, and then click the css href link to see if its broken). However, as you pointed out, the problem was the extra scrip tag. Removed it and the script works now :)